# How to use sendmail from Tcl

Tags: tcl, sendmail

How do I send mail to multiple recipients in To and Cc using sendmail in Tcl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to actually use sendmail, build up the message as a string and use the exec `<<` option to pass it to sendmail's stdin:

```
set msg {From: someone}
append msg \n "To: " [join $recipient_list ,]
append msg \n "Cc: " [join $cc_list ,]
append msg \n "Subject: $subject"
append msg \n\n $body

exec /usr/lib/sendmail -oi -t << $msg
```

Comment: You can use the Tcllib mime package to build the message. See especially `mime::setheader` and `mime::buildmessage`. http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/mime.html

Comment: it says `Keyword 'msg' not expected` know why.?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the smtp package, see e.g.: [SMTP package docu](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/smtp.html) or [Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1256).

I think you could e.g. do:

```
  package require smtp
  package require mime

  set token [mime::initialize -canonical text/plain -string $body]
  smtp::sendmessage $token \
          -header [list Subject $subject] \
          -header [list To [join $recipient_list ","]] \
          -header [list Cc [join $cc_list ","]]
  mime::finalize $token
```

Comment: You can also specify those headers in a single option by passing in a longer list or dictionary: `-header [list Subject $subj To [join $recips ", "]]`

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
echo "Subject: test" | /usr/lib/sendmail -v you@domain.com
```